# Uniform convergence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I got
$$
 f_n(x) = \frac{3x^2 (\frac 1 {n^2} + x^2) - 2x^4} { (\frac 1 {n^2} +x^2) ^2}
$$ on $[-1,1]$.

I have already proven that it converges pointwise to 
$$
 f(x) := \begin{cases}
1 & x \neq 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Can someone tell me if this sequence converges uniform to $f$, too ?

Comment: Is the pointwise limit continuous?

Comment: Alternatively, what is $f_n(1/n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you calculated correctly the limit function, then $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent. as  your $f$ is not continous.

Here is a result you may know: if $f_n$ are all continous on a domain $D$ and if they converge uniformly on $D$, the limit function must be  continuos.

your $f_n$ are all continous but limit function is not.

Comment: Yes, sure :) Thanks.

Comment: @André you are welcome!